# For $n≥3$, how many $n$ digit numbers are there such that each digit is 1, 2 or 3 is used and the digits contain 1,2,3 each at least once?

Tags: combinatorics

I think the total possible number that can be formed using 1,2,3 is $3^n$.
However, how to figure out the number of number that does not contain 1,2,3 at all?

Comment: @player3236:  based on the title I believe the question is how to remove the numbers from the $3^n$ that do not have all three digits included.  The other digits are still not allowed.  This is an inclusion-exclusion problem.  OP has not indicated that they recognize that.

Comment: @player3236:  yes, but I think that is an English problem.  I think the correct statement is how many $n$ digit strings on $\{1,2,3\}$ have at least one of each digit?

Answer (score 1):

We use inclusion/exclusion: the count of $n$-digit numbers with only digits $1,2$ is $2^n$, and same for $1,3$ and $2,3$. There's obviously only one $n$-digit number with only the digit $1$. So the final answer is $3^n-3\cdot2^n+3$.